# How do I consolidate build artifacts from subprojects in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Apologies if this is covered elsewhere, I'm afraid I couldn't find an answer to this particular trivial question.

I have a maven project which references and builds 4 sub projects (as bundles). I have set the dependencies between the sub-projects correctly and ultimately I get 4 different .jar files build built:

- parentproj/sub1/target/sub1.jar
- parentproj/sub2/target/sub2.jar
- parentproj/sub3/target/sub3.jar
- parentproj/sub4/target/sub4.jar

My question is, how do I set-up mu parent build so that when I build from the main .POM file, all 4 jars are placed in "/parentproj/target/..."?

An additional question is, how do I also build a xxxx-ALL.jar (that merges the contents of these 4 bundles)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) with the "dir" format to put them all in a folder, and the "jar" format to group them into a jar.

Some more details:

1. You start with your maven projects (let's call them subprojects)
2. Create a new maven project (pom packaging) that aggregates all the subprojects using < module > tags
3. Put in the assembly plugin into your pom.xml file (see below)
4. Create the correct assembly.xml file (see below)

pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
                <id>distro-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <finalName>somefolder</finalName>
                    <attach>false</attach>
                    <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                <phase>package</phase>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

assembly.xml file:

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>SomeName</id>
<formats>
    <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>
<baseDirectory></baseDirectory>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>appfiles</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>

<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <!-- useAllReactorProjects must be false if the assembly's run on the project with the module list -->
        <useAllReactorProjects>false</useAllReactorProjects>
        <includeSubModules>false</includeSubModules>

        <binaries>
            <includeDependencies>true</includeDependencies>
            <outputDirectory>bundle</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
        </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

Comment: I think you are right here, but I can't figure out how to configure the Assembly plugin even using the documentation. I just want to consolidate all the 'jar files made from the sub-projects into one root 'target' folder.

Comment: Yup, it's a pain to configure. Also, it takes forever to execute compared to normal compilation! Anyway, I've added my descriptors to the original answer. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank Miquel, I've set this as the accepted answer . Just because I hate the correct solution, it doesn't make you any less correct :)

Answer (score 1):

> An additional question is, how do I also build a xxxx-ALL.jar (that merges the contents of these 4 bundles)?

You can create an uber-jar (a jar with all the dependencies of the project) with [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html). Just create another project with these as dependencies and generate this uber-jar.